# Eclipselink fetching recursive entities gives incomplete result

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have the following problem, which I think is related to caching but I can't get it to work.

Config: Glassfish 3.1, JPA 2, EJB3.1, Eclipselink 2.2.

During a process I generate an UpdatePackage with several UpdatePackageFiles. These files are linked to the parent UpdatePackage but also have a recursive relation to its own.
For instance I have a Package which is a ZIP bundle with several files.
The process creates the UpdatePackage and the files in the database. So far so good.

After that a second process starts (different process, new transactions etc). And then I get the UpdatePackage with all the files, BUT, here is the problem: the internal hierarchy between the files is not complete. So, if I get the TOP UpdatePackageFile that file has one child, but that child does not contains any children, although there should be 2. Note, the database is correct.

If I restart the Application server and run the second process again, the hierarchy is complete.

I run the following query

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT pck FROM UpdatePackageSubscription pck "
  + " LEFT JOIN FETCH pck.updatePackage"
  + " JOIN pck.updatePackage g LEFT JOIN FETCH g.updatePackageFiles "
  + " JOIN g.updatePackageFiles q LEFT JOIN FETCH q.updatePackageFiles"
  + " JOIN q.updatePackageFiles z LEFT JOIN FETCH z.updatePackageFiles"
  + " WHERE pck.subscription.eps.id = :id "
  + " AND pck.subscription.applicationSubcategory.shortName = :shortName"
  + " AND pck.status != :done AND pck.status != :obsolete "
  + " ORDER BY pck.updatePackage.id");

query.setParameter("id", id);
query.setParameter("shortName", shortName);
query.setParameter("done", UpdatePackageSubscriptionStatusType.DONE);
query.setParameter("obsolete", UpdatePackageSubscriptionStatusType.OBSOLETE);
query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH");
```

You can see I explicitly run a lower level hierarchy join to force a fetch. And I also set the cache to REFRESH. I also added the following to my persistence.xml

```
<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false" />
```

I have the following entities, all is set to EAGER fetching.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UPDATE_PACKAGE_SUBSCRIPTION")
public class UpdatePackageSubscription implements Serializable {
  private UpdatePackage updatePackage;

  // bi-directional many-to-one association to UpdatePackage
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
  @JoinColumn(name = "UPP_ID", nullable = false)
  public UpdatePackage getUpdatePackage() {
    return this.updatePackage;
  }

  public void setUpdatePackage(UpdatePackage updatePackage) {
    this.updatePackage = updatePackage;
  }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "UPDATE_PACKAGE")
public class UpdatePackage implements Serializable {
  private List<UpdatePackageFile> updatePackageFiles = new ArrayList<UpdatePackageFile>();
  private List<UpdatePackageSubscription> updatePackageSubscriptions = new ArrayList<UpdatePackageSubscription>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "updatePackage", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @OrderBy
  public List<UpdatePackageFile> getUpdatePackageFiles() {
    return this.updatePackageFiles;
  }

  public void setUpdatePackageFiles(List<UpdatePackageFile> updatePackageFiles) {
    this.updatePackageFiles = updatePackageFiles;
  }

  // bi-directional many-to-one association to UpdatePackageSubscription
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "updatePackage", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
  @PrivateOwned
  public List<UpdatePackageSubscription> getUpdatePackageSubscriptions() {
    return this.updatePackageSubscriptions;
  }

  public void setUpdatePackageSubscriptions(List<UpdatePackageSubscription> updatePackageSubscriptions) {
    this.updatePackageSubscriptions = updatePackageSubscriptions;
  }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "UPDATE_PACKAGE_FILE")
public class UpdatePackageFile implements Serializable {    
  private UpdatePackage updatePackage;
  private UpdatePackageFile updatePackageFile;
  private List<UpdatePackageFile> updatePackageFiles;

  // bi-directional many-to-one association to UpdatePackage
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "UPP_ID", nullable = false)
  public UpdatePackage getUpdatePackage() {
    return this.updatePackage;
  }

  public void setUpdatePackage(UpdatePackage updatePackage) {
    this.updatePackage = updatePackage;
  }

  // bi-directional many-to-one association to UpdatePackageFile
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_FILE_ID")
  public UpdatePackageFile getUpdatePackageFile() {
    return this.updatePackageFile;
  }

  public void setUpdatePackageFile(UpdatePackageFile updatePackageFile) {
    this.updatePackageFile = updatePackageFile;
  }

  // bi-directional many-to-one association to UpdatePackageFile
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "updatePackageFile", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @PrivateOwned
  @OrderBy
  public List<UpdatePackageFile> getUpdatePackageFiles() {
    return this.updatePackageFiles;
  }

  public void setUpdatePackageFiles(List<UpdatePackageFile> updatePackageFiles) {
    this.updatePackageFiles = updatePackageFiles;
  }
}
```

So, my query is apparently correct, but still the hierarchy is incompletely fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to maintain both sides of a relationship.  You are most likely setting a ManyToOne but not adding to the OneToMany.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side

You could also disable the shared cache, but your code would still be wrong, and you would still be corrupting your objects in your persistence context.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F

Comment: pff, I knew that and I had that implemented but I forgot it on one place, this caused the confusion. Thanks!